# How can I optimize bucket usage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I use Google Buckets to serve JS files for websites. When I use AWS solution I use S3 and CloudFront together but I only use Google buckets for this purpose right now.

Is there any solution for cache-ing and optimizing Google invoices for serving static files? What are the best practices?

Comment: Could you please share what you've tried so far and what are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage use the Google CDN to cache your static file and thus optimize your bucket access and the response time for the user. You can [control the cache in the metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-cache)

In addition, if you serve your website with Cloud Storage, it is served only in HTTP. If you prefer HTTPS, maybe for improving the confidence of the user and discarding any browser warning message, put a [loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/) in front of it and serve the static file with a bucket backend. Don't forget to check the CDN checkbox..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use Google Cloud in order to serve JS files. How can I optimize this type of usage?

Comment: What do you want to optimise? You already have a multi-regional replication of your static files and cached automatically in CDN. Which part is painful?

Comment: I start to got high invoices. I want to reduce it. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you wan't to optimize cost, have you tried [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)?